# Mat to unsigned char*

Tags: c++, opencv

Can anyone tell me how can I convert `Mat` to `unsigned char*` in OpenCV and also whether the  data will be an array? Also, I want to know how can the same thing be done for `vector<vector<double>>` to `float*` so as to make it a pointer of array? thanks.

Comment: What type of Mat you are using? Anyway, see the cv::Mat.data member - it is a pointer to internal Mat storage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As was already mentioned you should use a `data` member of `cv::Mat`:

```
cv::Mat m;
...
uchar *data = m.data;
```

About your second question:
first of all, when you convert from `double` to `float` you lose some data. And there's no ready solution to do that so just use simple cycle and copy vector to the array-pointer:

```
float* toArray(vector<vector<double> >& arr)
{
    if (arr.empty())
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        //I assume that each vector (element of arr) has the same size
        int m = arr.size();
        int n = arr[0].size();
        float *res = new float[m * n];
        int count = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                res[count++] = (float) arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this what you mean for the second question?

float * kernelarr = nullptr;
    for (int row = 0; row < vec.size(); row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < vec[row].size(); col++) {
            kernelarr = &vec[row][col];
        }